# Using the SASS rgba function in a CSS variable context?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, material-components-web

How do we get SASS `rgba` to turn `rgba(#4caf50, 0.1)` into `rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.1)` when the context is the value side of the CSS variable declaration?

For my clarity here's an example:

```
$green: #4caf50;

$green-rgba: rgba($green, 0.1);
@debug $green-rgba; // rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.1)
```

The `@debug` statement will log `rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.1)`, which is correct.

However if we try this:

```
test {
    --mat-mdc-button-ripple-color: rgba(#4caf50, 0.1);
}
```

The compiled result is:

```
test {
  --mat-mdc-button-ripple-color: rgba(#4caf50, 0.1);
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

OK - After studying the source for the Angular Material button the ripple code does it like this and it works:

```
--mat-mdc-button-ripple-color:  #{rgba($color, 0.1)};
```